# Reading C++ code CreateFrame function (from C# prespective)

Tags: c#, c++, c, frame, creation

```
// Create test video frame
void CreateFrame(char * buffer, int w, int h, int bytespan)
{
  int wxh = w * h;
  static float seed = 1.0;
  for (int i = 0; i < h; i ++)
  {
    char* line = buffer + i * bytespan;
    for (int j = 0; j < w; j ++)
    {
      // RGB
      line[0] = 255 * sin(((float)i / wxh * seed) * 3.14);
      line[1] = 255 * cos(((float)j / wxh * seed) * 3.14);
      line[2] = 255 * sin(((float)(i + j) / wxh * seed) * 3.14);
      line += 3;
    }
  }
  seed = seed + 2.2;
}
```

can any one please tall me what is `line += 3;` for?

and how to create such function analog in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C/C++, the value `line` in line is actually a memory address of an array, and `line[1]` actually represents the value at the address of the variable `line` plus a 1 item offset. (If the type of the items in `line` is an `int`, then it means the address of `line` plus four bytes; since it is a `char`, it means the address of `line` plus one byte.)

So, `line += 3` means that `line[1]` is now equivalent to `[old "line" value][4]`.  The coder could have written the code as:

```
for (int j = 0; j < w; j ++)
{
  // RGB
  line[(3 * j)] = 255 * sin(((float)i / wxh * seed) * 3.14);
  line[(3 * j) + 1] = 255 * cos(((float)j / wxh * seed) * 3.14);
  line[(3 * j) + 2] = 255 * sin(((float)(i + j) / wxh * seed) * 3.14);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`line += 3` increments the pointer `line` by 3 bytes, so that it points to the next pixel.  `line` here is a pointer to a 3-byte pixel, so it really should be called something else, like `pPixel`.

Answer (score 3):

Line is a pointer to a position within buffer. Incrementing line advances the processing down the buffer.

A C# analog might be:

```
static float seed = 1.0f;
static void CreateFrame(byte[] buffer, int w, int h, int bytespan)
{
  int wxh = w * h;
  for (int i = 0; i < h; i ++)
  {
    int line = i * bytespan;
    for (int j = 0; j < w; j ++)
    {
      // RGB
      buffer[line + 0] = (byte)(255 * Math.Sin(((float)i / wxh * seed) * 3.14));
      buffer[line + 1] = (byte)(255 * Math.Cos(((float)j / wxh * seed) * 3.14));
      buffer[line + 2] = (byte)(255 * Math.Sin(((float)(i + j) / wxh * seed) * 3.14));
      line += 3;
    }
  }
  seed = seed + 2.2f;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is pointer arithmetic. Since you are dealing with 3 elements of the array in one go you will need to update the pointer suitably otherwise you will be reading the same location twice and of course, erroneously.

Answer (score 1):

You would replace the pointer by a byte array and index into it by an integer as follows:

```
// Create test video frame
void CreateFrame(byte[] buffer, int w, int h, int bytespan)
{
  int wxh = w * h;
  static float seed = 1.0;
  for (int i = 0; i < h; i ++)
  {
    int line = i * bytespan;
    for (int j = 0; j < w; j ++)
    {
      // RGB
      buffer[line + 0] = 255 * sin(((float)i / wxh * seed) * 3.14);
      buffer[line + 1] = 255 * cos(((float)j / wxh * seed) * 3.14);
      buffer[line + 2] = 255 * sin(((float)(i + j) / wxh * seed) * 3.14);
      line += 3;
    }
  }
  seed = seed + 2.2;
}
```

I just left the variable name as `line`, even if from what I understand, it is not really a line.